# std::cin.getline(f_name, 10)

Tags: c++, std, getline, cin

If I have for example the following statements:

```
char f_name[11];
std::cin.getline(f_name,10);
```

Does thia mean:
* Declare a string with 11-characters wide?
* Read the entered line and pass it as the value for "f_name"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct!

```
char f_name[11];
```

declares the array `f_name` with `11` elements.

```
std::cin.getline(f_name,10);
```

prompts for the value to be entered, which then stores it in `f_name[11]`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and no.

```
char f_name[11];
```

declares an array of `char` with 11 elements. It's not really a string - you could consider it a "C string" if it had a NUL (`'\0'`) at the end (which it does not).

```
std::cin.getline(f_name, 10);
```

May or may not read the entire entered line, because it only reads up to 9 chars. You need **not** make the buffer larger than the value given to `cin.getline`.

Unless you have a specific reason not to, use `std::getline` to read a line in C++. An example below.

```
#include <string>
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
```